# Is a height-balanced tree a tree where a node with exactly one child must have a leaf as its only child?

Tags: data-structures, tree

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees says:

> A balanced binary tree is a binary tree structure in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1.

Is it equivalent to say that a binary tree is height-balanced if a node with exactly one child must have a leaf as its only child?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it equivalent to say that a binary tree is height-balanced if a node with exactly one child must have a leaf as its only child?

No. This is a correct observation about balanced binary trees, but it is not a complete *definition* of balanced binary trees. While all balanced trees have this property, it is easy to produce  *unbalanced* trees that also have this property.

---

To start, your observation is correct when applied to balanced trees:

In a **binary** tree, a node  with only one child **still has two subtrees**, one of which is empty and has a height of 0. By definition, in a *balanced* binary tree, the other non-empty subtree must have a height of 0 or 1. So, if the node has one child, then that child is necessarily a leaf node with a subtree height of 1, resulting in subtree heights of 0 and 1. Anything but a leaf node is an unbalanced tree with subtree heights of 0 and >1.

For example, consider a node A which has as its left child a leaf node B, and no right child:

```
   A
  /
 B
```

The heights of A's left subtree is 1, and its right subtree is 0, so this is a balanced tree: The difference in heights is 1.

If A continues to have a single child B, and *any* node exists under B such that it is not a leaf, then A's left subtree height becomes greater than 1, while the right subtree height remains 0:

```
    A
   /
  B
 /
C
```

This is by definition *not* a balanced tree.

---

**However**, it is possible, and easy, to produce an unbalanced binary tree that still satisfies your modified definition:

> a binary tree is height-balanced if a node with exactly one child must have a leaf as its only child?

The following tree satisfies this criteria: The only node with 1 child, `D`, has a leaf node as its child. However, the tree is clearly not balanced:

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   / \
  D   E
 /
F
```

You could extend the left subtree indefinitely, and it would still satisfy your criteria; only the second to last node needs to have one child which is a leaf, all other nodes have either 0 or 2 children.

```
            A
           / \
          B   C
         / \
        D   E
       / \
      F   G
     / \
    H   I
   / \
  J   K
 /
L
```